# Does Google Maps API support offline maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to know is google map support the offline map download by the API?I find nothing in the Google map documents for Android.

Comment: just search in google man, there are many article: https://www.scribd.com/document/233761890/How-to-Use-the-Offline-Google-Map-API-to-Load-Offline-Google-Maps

Answer (score 0):

According to its [terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/) , online account logging is needed to use the service.

> 1.3 Accounts.  Customer must have an Account to access the Admin Console through which Customer may administer its use of the Services.

But you could try some third-party libraries, for example:
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles

Comment: If customer already have an online account.How can i download the offlineMap with the google map api.I don't find any Api can use to downLoad a place.thanks~